# How to provide the values of Hive-site.xml Internally instead of refering to the path on execution of Spark Jar

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hive, apache-spark-sql

I'm having a piece of code to fetch Tables from Hive to spark and it works fine, for that I'm placing Hive-site.xml file in resource folder of eclipse.

Down the line I convert the code to jar file and refer the path of the Hive-site.xml file to execute the program.

Is there is any why I can use the values of Hive-site.xml internally(in the program itself) to override that file referencing part?

Code below:

```
val appConf = ConfigFactory.load()
val conf = new SparkConf().
  setAppName("hivedb").setMaster(appConf.getConfig(args(0)).getString("deploymentMaster"))
val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
val hc = new HiveContext(sc)

val source = hc.sql("SELECT * from sample.source").rdd.map(_.mkString(","))
val destination = hc.sql("select * from sample.destination").rdd.map(_.mkString(","))
```

Hive-site.xml file values:

```
<configuration>
<property>
<name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionURL</name>
<value>jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/metastore?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true</value>
</property>

 <property>
<name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionUserName</name>
<value>hiveroot</value>   
  </property>

 <property>
<name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionPassword</name>
<value>hivepassword</value>   
  </property>

 <property>
<name>hive.exec.scratchdir</name>
<value>/tmp/hive/${user.name}</value>   
  </property>

</configuration>
```

I'm looking for something like below:

```
 val url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/metastore?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true"
val user = "hiveroot"
val password = "hivepassword"
val src ="/tmp/hive/${user.name}"
val a = hc.read.format("jdbc").options(Map("javax.jdo.option.ConnectionURL" -> url,    
  "user" -> user,
  "password" -> password,
  "sql" -> "sample.source",
  "hive.exec.scratchdir"->src)).load().collect().foreach(println)
```

using only the required values of Hive-site.xml file inside the program without the need of referring to the file.

as suggested by Raktotpal Bordoloi

```
 val warehouseLocation = "/usr/hive/warehouse"
val spark = SparkSession.builder().master("local")
.appName("spark session example")
.config("javax.jdo.option.ConnectionURL","jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/metastore?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true")
  .config("javax.jdo.option.ConnectionUserName","hiveroot")
  .config("javax.jdo.option.ConnectionPassword","hivepassword")
  .config("hive.exec.scratchdir","/tmp/hive/${user.name}")
  .config("spark.sql.warehouse.dir", warehouseLocation)
 // .config("hive.metastore.uris", "thrift://localhost:9083")      
  .enableHiveSupport()
  .getOrCreate()
```

import spark.implicits._
import spark.sql

sql("select * from sample.source").collect.foreach(println)

Thank you!

Comment: How do you plan on getting the data from a file without referring to it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Spark 2.0 you can set "spark.sql.warehouse.dir" on the SparkSession's builder, before creating a SparkSession. It should propagate correctly while creating Hive-Context.

```
val spark = SparkSession.builder()
.config("spark.sql.warehouse.dir", "...")
.config("hive.metastore.uris", "thrift://localhost:9083")
```

When the mode is remote (in the above case), configurations like "javax.jdo.option.ConnectionURL" will not be used (because they are used by remote metastore server that talks to the database).

For Spark 1.6, you need to place the hive-site.xml in classpath.

Comment: Thank you Raktotpal Bordoloi, its working fine without any issues, you saved me again :) but its not taking this value in conf .config("hive.metastore.uris", "thrift://localhost:9083") throwing some error like Error while instantiating 'org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveSessionState'.

Comment: I have one concerns kindly have a look 1.Now I'm running in localhost so I can easily removed it what if I have the metastore in remote.

Comment: What is your hiverserver version?

In case u run on hiverser2; u should put the conf like `conf .config("hive.metastore.uris", "hive2://localhost:9083")`

Comment: I'm trying to access a table in hive2 resides in remote machine same network. got these error Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Error while instantiating 'org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveSessionState'. I used like this .config("hive.metastore.uris", "hive2://remoteservername:9083")

Comment: Sorry to mention that; hiveserver1 or hiveserver2 are diff service than metastore service.

Comment: hiveserver2 service is responsible when you are using hive-jdbc connection to connect to hive.

Comment: So, to connect to metastore service, you have to use `thrift` protocol only as `thrift://localhost:9083`

Comment: Dnt forget to start hive-metastore service separately in your server.